# How to initialize Gregorian calendar with date as YYYY-MM-DD format?

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I have a class which contains a variable

```
private GregorianCalendar cal;
```

Now I want to initialize it with a date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, I tried using the default constructor but the output I get is something like this `"2017-05-25T14:36:52+03:00"`, I only want `"2017-05-25"` date part?

How do I achieve it?

Comment: If you have the choice, don't use GregorianCalendar but java time (in Java 8+) or Joda., which have proper "LocalDate" classes.

Comment: You need to format the date. Check [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). If you want some specific help with your code you should write your attempt in your question.

Comment: "Now I want to initialize it with a date in yyyy-mm-dd format" - a date doesn't have a format in either `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar`. Apply formatting at the point where you convert the value to a string.

Comment: I tried using the SimpleDateFormat but it returns string, how do i store a string in variable whose data type is GregorianCalendar?

Comment: The final output should be in cal variable

Comment: I sounds like you’ve misunderstood. Try to keep two concepts apart: the value of a variable and the presentation of the same variable. Just as an `int` that holds a 7 can be printed as 7 or 07, 007 or +7, your `GregorianCalendar` can be printed as `2017-05-25T14:36:52+03:00` or just `2017-05-25`. In both cases, that variable holds the same value.

Comment: And just as there is no such thing as storing a string into an `int` variable in Java, there is also no such think as storing a string in a `GregorianCalendar`.

Comment: It seems to me that what you are really asking for, is a `LocalDate` to use instead of your `GregorianCalendar`. Its default format is `2017-05-25` (just as integers and `GregorianCalendar` at may be formatted into other formats if desired).

Comment: @OleV.V.: `LocalDate` would be better in terms of an API, but that doesn't have a format either, and the OP really needs to understand that there's a difference between the fundamental data and a string representation of that.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I need to pass only LocaleDate and I  am using GregorianCalendar, and I am using JAVA 7 so i cannot use java time

Comment: @SachinChaudhari Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Avoid the troublesome old legacy date-time classes; they are a wretched mess.

Answer (score 3):

First, you may hate me for reiterating, you need to understand that there’s a difference between a date and a string representation of that date; a difference between the fundamental data and a string representation of it.

Second, you *can* use `LocalDate` (and the other Java date and time classes) with Java 7 if you want. It is (and they are all) in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) , a back-port of the Java SE 8 date-time classes to Java SE 6 and 7.

Since I gather that `LocalDate` fits your requirements *much* better, I really think you should give it a thought or two. So instead of your `cal` I suggest

```
private LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Also think about whether you want the current time zone setting of your JVM (as the above will give you) or you want to control which time zone you use. It will make a difference.

Finally, if you really insist. As you have understood by now, I cannot give you a string *in* a `GregorianCalendar`. You may discard the time part of your `GregorianCalendar` so you only have the date part. And you may format it into a string of your liking.

```
public class GregorianCalendarDemo {

    private GregorianCalendar cal;

    public GregorianCalendarDemo() {
        cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
        // discard time of day so we only have the date
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    }

    protected GregorianCalendar getCal() {
        return cal;
    }

    public String getFormattedCal() {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return format.format(getCal().getTime());
    }
}
```

When I just called `getFormattedCal()`, it returned `2017-05-25`.

Again, decide whether default values for time zone and locale are fine or you want something else.

You might have thought that we could discard the hours with just `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0):`, and similarly with minutes and seconds. It would work in 99 % of all cases at least. However, with transistion to summer time (daylight savings time), the day is not guaranteed to begin at 0 hours, so the above code is more bulletproof.

### Link

[ThreeTen Backport home](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `SimpleDateFormat` for example :

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
format.setCalendar(cal);
String result = format.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(result);//today is 2017-05-25
```

---

To convert String to `GregorianCalendar` :

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssX");
Date date = format.parse("2017-05-25T14:36:52+03:00");
GregorianCalendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();
cal2.setTime(date);
```

Comment: I tried using the SimpleDateFormat but it returns string, how do i store a string in variable whose data type is GregorianCalendar?

Comment: I dont want to print the data, i want to send it in a XML tag  but i need to send  the date in yyyy-mm-dd format .

Comment: then send a String instead of `GregorianCalendar`