# How does the Date type get the 'YY-MM-DD'?

Tags: java, date

I want to get a present time.The Date type of 'YY-MM-DD'.What should I do?

Comment: Please clarify your problem space and show pertinent code, both to help us understand you question.

Comment: I know the desired format in that other question is not the same, but the way to do is the same, so I trust you to tailor the answers from the other question to the format you are asking for.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using Java 8+, use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```
String text = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy-MM-dd"));
```

In earlier versions, use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) like

```
String text = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
```

While you can use the later in more recent versions, the former is generally preferred because date and time handling has been greatly improved by the [`java.time` classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the below code.

```
public void getCurrentTimeStampInYYMMDDFormat() {
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
}
```

If you are using **JDK8** then, you can also do it like this:

```
public void getCurrentTimeStampInYYMMDDFormat() {
    String date = LocalDateTime.now()
       .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy-MM-dd"));
}
```

Comment: Obviously ... he needs to modify the pattern if he wants to display the date as YY-MM-DD.  The details are **in the javadocs**.

Comment: But the return type I need is Date.

Comment: @blueblueblue please check now.

Comment: @blueblueblue Edit your Question to make clear your requirements.

Comment: Ah, one more of those. @blueblueblue, a `Date` cannot have a specific format in it, it’s just a point in time. How you format it lies outside the `Date` object.

Comment: See for example the discussions under [this question: How to initialize Gregorian calendar with date as YYYY-MM-DD format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180575/how-to-initialize-gregorian-calendar-with-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd-format) That is about `GregorianCalendar`, but no matter if we are talking `Date` or `GregorianCalendar` or `int`, the truth is the same: the variable does not (cannot) hold a string presentation in it.